# Web Service with Eclipse for WebSphere 8.0

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, websphere

I am trying to create a Web Service with Eclipse to host on WebSphere 8.0.

```
package peter.td.com;

import javax.jws.*;

@WebService
public class First01 {
    @WebMethod
    public int Addition(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return a+b+c;
    }
}
```

I did export(.ear) and took the EAR file and deployed it at WAS 8.0.
when I do `http://localhost:9080/WebService01`:
its giving me an page not found error.

I looked all around and I couldn't find any good example to create Web Service to host on WebSphere.  I am using Eclipse IDE.

Please share or show me any tutorial link that I can create WebService for WAS 8.0 with Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is incorrect. It should be `http://localhost:9080/context-root/First01Service`
where context-root is by default your web project name.
The easiest way to get correct url and test service in Eclipse is to add project to the server, then expand "Services" folder in your project, right click your web service and select Test with Web Service Explorer.